# Is there any way to know why a contract call cannot work through web3.py?

Tags: web3.py, python

I have a deployed smart contract and attempt to write codes to call it through `web3.py`. I'm getting the following error when I call `estimateGas()`.

`ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction'}`

Due to I'm just estimating gas, I guess it should be impossible to have not enough gas. So the error should be caused by `always failing transaction`.

The contract function indeed has some `require` parts that verify something before executing the logics, like the following:

```
require(
   !traderNonces[msg.sender][_nonce],
   "Failed to call function due to replay attack."
);
```

However, I cannot ensure which part causes the error. Is there any chance that I can get the error message, such as the above message `Failed to call function due to replay attack.`, in `web3.py`, so I can at least know the reason of failure?

Comment: In some clients like ganache `estimateGas` execute the transaction so the maximum gas available is the block gas limit, if you need more you have to explicitely set it.

Comment: In my case I connect to Ethereum through infura API. Does infura API have this kind of characteristic?

Comment: There's an unaswered question about estimateGas from web3.py using infura https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48494/gas-estimation-fails-on-expensive-contract-functions-infura, and a closed github issue https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/845. It appears to be an infura limitation, estimateGas fails for complex transactions.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Brownie](https://github.com/iamdefinitelyahuman/brownie), which displays the specific error message when a transaction (or gas estimate) fails:

```py
>>> contract.myFunction()
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "eth_brownie-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/brownie/network/contract.py", line 455, in __call__
    return self.call(*args)
  File "eth_brownie-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/brownie/network/contract.py", line 359, in call
    raise VirtualMachineError(e) from None
VirtualMachineError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Failed to call function due to replay attack.
```

The specific error string is available as `VirtualMachineError.revert_msg`:

```py
>>> try:
...     t.myFunction()
... except Exception as exc:
...     print(exc.revert_msg)
... 
Failed to call function due to replay attack.
```

See the Brownie [documentation on debugging contracts](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debug.html#revert-strings) for more info.

Disclosure: I am the lead developer of Brownie.

Comment: Thanks, helpful feature that Brownie provides

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably because you don't have `bool`eans in `traderNonces[msg.sender][_nonce]`.

In [the docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/control-structures.html), it's stated that:

> Note that there is no type conversion from non-boolean to boolean
>   types as there is in C and JavaScript, so if (1) { ... } is not valid
>   Solidity.

Assuming `_nonce`s should be positive integers, you can change your `require` to:

```
require(
   !(traderNonces[msg.sender][_nonce] > 0),
   "Failed to call function due to replay attack."
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In my smart contract, the value is defined as boolean. So changing the condition will make the compile fail.